# Large matrix manipulation in multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have:

- matrix 20*40000 of floats M - `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`;
- 1000 values X;
- ~2000000 POD structures S.

A typical situation is: for each value from X I take several structs from S and change some ranges in rows of M (these ranges can overlap); then I go through the M and count these changes to receive desired output.

So I have 2 problems:

1. I have to store t copies of M (for now I create them in kind of a pool and then get `thread_local` reference for each thread)
2. I have to call `std::fill(M[i].begin(), M[i].end(), 0);` before each iteration and I see it's consuming the time.

And questions:

1. Is the approach with thread_local reference appropriate?
2. How to deal with `std::fill()`? How can it be improved?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise about how S, X and M are related, what these changes do and what "count these changes to receive desired output" means? Honestly, I find your description quite incomprehensible. Maybe giving an example might help?

Comment: Furthermore, it seems you always start with M=0 (all entries zero), correct? What percentage of entries will typically become non-zero during your mysterious operations? If it is only a small percentage, maybe a sparse matrix representation may be useful? If that is the case, setting M to zero won't need a fill operation any more.

Comment: Nothing mysterious. I just don't want to overcomplicate the description with field-specific details. Connection, as I said, is quite straightforward: I take value from X -> take several corresponding values from S (~20 structs) then for each struct from S and value from X I can receive several ranges (not sure, how much each time, have to measure), then I have to accumulate these ranges. Final loop over M rows shows me if I have some range of values over a particular threshold.

Comment: Won't sparse matrix approach become a bottleneck in case of these ~20 overlapping ranges I first have to merge and then iterate over this merged rsange?

Comment: But what size and shape are those "ranges"? What kind of changes are implied on M? What do you mean by "accumulate ranges"  precisely? And you did not answer my question about the expected percentage of value becoming nonzero. Honestly, if someone else would have given you such a fragmentary description, I guess you would have problems to understand them as well.

Comment: ... and I cannot tell you if a sparse matrix approach becomes a bottleneck due to lack of understanding of those details.

Comment: First of all, thank you Doc. Here are answers: 1. Range - just a sequence of floats. Linear. 2. I've mentioned, that I have to calculate actual lengths of the ranges.  3. M stores this ranges in its rows. 4. e.g. r1 = {000110}, r2 = {001100} -> M[3] = {001210} 5. nonzero percentage is to be calculated as well

Comment: Actually, I receive each range not as a whole row (with a lot of zeros), but as a starting position in a row and number of elements. If it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76816/discussion-between-user1056837-and-doc-brown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the replies.

Finally I came up with a solution:

I continue usage a pool of such matrixes. And it works quite fine for me.

The interesting thing was that `std::vector<>::resize(the_same_vector.capacity())` works times faster then `std::fill()` or `std::memset(&vector[0], 0, vector.size())`

Comment: I am **very sceptical** that your `resize` is actually faster than `std::fill` (or `std::memset`). That would be a huge bug in the standard library implementation

Comment: @KonradRudolph, That's what I got.

Answer (score 3):

Nice as `std::vector` is, there are times when you need to step down a bit and use the OS.

In this case, it appears that your `M` matrix is hardly used, or else the updates would dominate. You must have <1 write on average for `std::fill` to be noticeable.

Of course, the very first thing to check if whether you create the copies of `M` in a single thread. I'm slightly worried by the fact that you say you create them in a pool and **then** create a `thread_local` reference.

In a further optimization, it can be helpful to flatten `M`.  Currently it's not contiguous, you have 20 vectors (and because of the copy, that's per thread). Use a 1D vector, and implement the 2D indexing yourself in a Matrix class with `float* Matrix::operator[](size_t dim1) { return &vec[i*40000]; }`.

Comment: Two remarks: “use the OS” — *how*? This point is not clear to me. Secondly, your suggested API for 2D indexing is a generally a bad idea, it’s better to provide an `operator ()(s_t i, s_t j)`. For margin views (which is what your code effectively does), if necessary, I’d provide a *function* that returns an iterator *range* (aka. view) rather than a single iterator.